# How to match several patterns, but each only once

Tags: grep, pattern-matching, large-files

I know that if I have a file of patterns I can use

```
grep -f pat_file search_file
```

to search the file normally. How would you approach performing this task so that the command looks for each pattern only once?

I'm looking for efficiency, so it might be that simply writing a python program is the most efficient way to do it, but I bet there's something out there.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with grep... please add sample input for both files and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in awk:

```
FNR == NR { pattern[NR] = $0; next }

{
    for (i in pattern) {
        if ($0 ~ pattern[i]) {
            print
            delete pattern[i]
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

To be called as follows:

```
awk -f script.awk patterns infile
```

where `patterns` contains your patterns and `infile` is the file you want to search.

The first command reads the patterns into an array; the second command (only executed for files after the first file) loops over the patterns, prints matching lines, deletes the pattern from the array and skips the rest of the patterns.

For an example input of

```
line with pattern1
another line with pattern1
line with pattern2
pattern1 again
pattern3 now
and pattern2
```

and a pattern file

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
```

the output is

```
$ awk -f script.awk patterns infile
line with pattern1
line with pattern2
pattern3 now
```

To optimize, you could add a check after the `delete` statement to see if there are any patterns left and exit if not.

Answer (score 0):

This MAY be what you're looking for:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { regexps[$0]; next }
{
    found = 0
    for (regexp in regexps) {
        if ($0 ~ regexp) {
            found = 1
            delete regexps[regexp]
        }
    }
}
found
' pat_file search_file
```

but since you haven't provided any testable sample input and expected output it's just an untested guess.

By the way - never use the word "pattern" to describe what type of matching you want as it's ambiguous, use "string" or "regexp", whichever you really mean.